# How to add a fast-scroller to the RecyclerView

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview, fastscroll, sectionindexer

### Background

On ListView, you could have a fast scroller which allowed you to drag a scrollbar to easily scroll to wherever you wished (using [**fastScrollEnabled**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled) attribute)

Together with "[**SectionIndexer**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)" class and optionally some attributes, you could have a nice popup that shows as you use this scrollbar (link [**here**](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/)).

Such a thing is shown on the contacts app so that you could scroll easily to specific letters.

### The problem

RecyclerView doesn't seem to have any of those. Not even a fast-scroll.

### The question

How do I add a fast scroller functionality for the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

New answer:
Over time I've noticed that my original answer had some drawbacks compared to other solutions, especially for fragments within ViewPager.

I suggest to either use the [**android-x solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905734/878126) in case you don't need a bubble, or a third party library ([**here**](https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll) is a nice one) in case you do.

---

old answer:

Since all third party libraries had issues, I've decided to gather what I can find (mostly from [**here**](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-2/#comment-67201)), fix everything and publish my own POC of the fast-scroller of the RecyclerView :

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller

usage:

1. make a RecyclerView.Adapter that implements BubbleTextGetter, which given a position in the data will return the text to show in the bubble-popup.
2. position the FastScroller inside the layout that container the RecyclerView (probably at the right area).
3. Customize the FastScroller FastScroller

Some disadvantages:

1. doesn't support orientation change, but it's probably easy to fix.
2. doesn't support other layoutManagers. Only LinearLayoutManager
3. Needs API 11 and above.

Code:

**BubbleTextGetter**

```
public interface BubbleTextGetter
  {
  String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos);
  }
```

**recycler_view_fast_scroller__fast_scroller.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/fastscroller_bubble"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="48sp" tools:text="A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/recycler_view_fast_scroller__bubble"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fastscroller_handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/recycler_view_fast_scroller__handle"/>

</merge>
```

**MainActivity**

```
...
fastScroller=(FastScroller)findViewById(R.id.fastscroller);
fastScroller.setRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**FastScroller**

```
public class FastScroller extends LinearLayout
  {
  private static final int BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION=100;
  private static final int TRACK_SNAP_RANGE=5;

  private TextView bubble;
  private View handle;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private final ScrollListener scrollListener=new ScrollListener();
  private int height;

  private ObjectAnimator currentAnimator=null;

  public FastScroller(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs,final int defStyleAttr)
    {
    super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr);
    initialise(context);
    }

  public FastScroller(final Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    initialise(context);
    }

  public FastScroller(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context,attrs);
    initialise(context);
    }

  private void initialise(Context context)
    {
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    setClipChildren(false);
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fast_scroller__fast_scroller,this,true);
    bubble=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fastscroller_bubble);
    handle=findViewById(R.id.fastscroller_handle);
    bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldw,int oldh)
    {
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    height=h;
    }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event)
    {
    final int action=event.getAction();
    switch(action)
      {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(event.getX()<handle.getX())
          return false;
        if(currentAnimator!=null)
          currentAnimator.cancel();
        if(bubble.getVisibility()==INVISIBLE)
          showBubble();
        handle.setSelected(true);
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        setPosition(event.getY());
        setRecyclerViewPosition(event.getY());
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        handle.setSelected(false);
        hideBubble();
        return true;
      }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

  public void setRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }

  private void setRecyclerViewPosition(float y)
    {
    if(recyclerView!=null)
      {
      int itemCount=recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
      float proportion;
      if(handle.getY()==0)
        proportion=0f;
      else if(handle.getY()+handle.getHeight()>=height-TRACK_SNAP_RANGE)
        proportion=1f;
      else
        proportion=y/(float)height;
      int targetPos=getValueInRange(0,itemCount-1,(int)(proportion*(float)itemCount));
      recyclerView.scrollToPosition(targetPos);
      String bubbleText=((BubbleTextGetter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).getTextToShowInBubble(targetPos);
      bubble.setText(bubbleText);
      }
    }

  private int getValueInRange(int min,int max,int value)
    {
    int minimum=Math.max(min,value);
    return Math.min(minimum,max);
    }

  private void setPosition(float y)
    {
    int bubbleHeight=bubble.getHeight();
    int handleHeight=handle.getHeight();
    handle.setY(getValueInRange(0,height-handleHeight,(int)(y-handleHeight/2)));
    bubble.setY(getValueInRange(0,height-bubbleHeight-handleHeight/2,(int)(y-bubbleHeight)));
    }

  private void showBubble()
    {
    AnimatorSet animatorSet=new AnimatorSet();
    bubble.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    if(currentAnimator!=null)
      currentAnimator.cancel();
    currentAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bubble,"alpha",0f,1f).setDuration(BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    currentAnimator.start();
    }

  private void hideBubble()
    {
    if(currentAnimator!=null)
      currentAnimator.cancel();
    currentAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bubble,"alpha",1f,0f).setDuration(BUBBLE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    currentAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
      {
      super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
      bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      currentAnimator=null;
      }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
      {
      super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
      bubble.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      currentAnimator=null;
      }
    });
    currentAnimator.start();
    }

  private class ScrollListener extends OnScrollListener
    {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView rv,int dx,int dy)
      {
      View firstVisibleView=recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
      int firstVisiblePosition=recyclerView.getChildPosition(firstVisibleView);
      int visibleRange=recyclerView.getChildCount();
      int lastVisiblePosition=firstVisiblePosition+visibleRange;
      int itemCount=recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
      int position;
      if(firstVisiblePosition==0)
        position=0;
      else if(lastVisiblePosition==itemCount-1)
        position=itemCount-1;
      else
        position=firstVisiblePosition;
      float proportion=(float)position/(float)itemCount;
      setPosition(height*proportion);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if your views vary in size? That is my problem right now. I do know what views would change. But not sure if I can use that to help me. I have several views that double in height.

Comment: Yeah, but this is lots of help. Its just a matter of me figuring out how to compensating for those offsets.

Comment: @LoyalRayne Please use the Github repo though. Here it might be un-updated.

Comment: Why my FastScroller doesn't include all the recycler view?? I follow all your step..but it doesn't show correctly, please help me @androiddeveloper

Comment: @MicheleLacorte Please try the github repo. It works well there.

Comment: You mean the code on github ? I tried @androiddeveloper

Comment: @MicheleLacorte Seems I forgot to add an import. Try now.

Comment: You're the best !, another simple question how come with the same settings your layout bar me ends up " under " the toolbar? I state that I use a collapsing toolbar..it's strange...

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I don't understand the question.

Comment: this bug : http://s11.postimg.org/52skjui03/Screenshot_2015_10_08_19_22_15.png @androiddeveloper

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I don't see this on my sample. How did you manage to do it on my sample ?

Comment: I use a scrollable toolbar, recyclerView has paddingTop = " ?Attr/actionBarSize" , for FastScroller use all his tricks layout, but when I get to the letter " A" the FastScroller continues to rise, doesn't stop at the beginning of the toolbar!..

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I don't understand. Is my sample ok or not for you? Please create a minimal sample, and ask a new question thread here. I can't help without understanding what you did.

Comment: No, not good , it's simple just look at the image above and you understand that the FastScroll should not stand in the toolbar is not it? @androiddeveloper

Comment: @MicheleLacorte For me my sample works fine . I think you've changed it.

Comment: Can I use this lib with minsdk 9+ ?? If not are there any alternatives that support minsdk 9? Gingerbread is really important to me (unfortunately)

Comment: @ThanosF I think it can have nineoldandroids for the animations part and this will make it support API 9 and above. I wanted to add this but didn't have the chance yet.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but, it doesn't automatically hide when the user has stopped scrolling: How can we modify the code to hide the Scroll View when the user has stopped scrolling?

Comment: @Jack You can use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) , and when onScrollStateChanged is called, decide if you wish to show the fast-scroller or not: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,int) . Do note that the fast-scroller is always visible on the contacts app.

Comment: this is a nice solution, but when I scrolls recycleview... handle view is not scrolling in starting and ending point..after some scroll its works...

Comment: @vishalpatel If you've found an issue on the repo, please publish a new issue on the repo website: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller/issues

Answer (score 53):

I stumbled on this question a few days ago when I ran into this situation. Here is my **example implementation of FastScroll for RecyclerView**:

#### [github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller)

Try running the example application, and peruse the code to see a fairly simple usage of a simple RecyclerViewFastScroller widget. There is information on github, but I'll include the basic usage here for a vertical fast scroller.

For a full example, refer to the [sample application in the repo](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller/tree/master/Application).

### Basic Usage

In the activity or fragment XML where your RecyclerView resides, include a VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller object. The following example would be in a relative layout:

```
...
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


  <xyz.danoz.recyclerviewfastscroller.vertical.VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller
      android:id="@+id/fast_scroller"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/however_wide_you_want_this"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
...
```

In your fragment or activity where you setup layout programmatically, hook up the fast scroller to the recycler:

```
...
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_frag, container, false);
      ...

      // Grab your RecyclerView and the RecyclerViewFastScroller from the layout
      RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
      VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller fastScroller = (VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fast_scroller);

      // Connect the recycler to the scroller (to let the scroller scroll the list)
      fastScroller.setRecyclerView(recyclerView);

      // Connect the scroller to the recycler (to let the recycler scroll the scroller's handle)
      recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(fastScroller.getOnScrollListener());

      ...
      return rootView;
  }
...
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: There is now added support for Android-Lollipop-Contacts-style section indicators! Check out the [sample application's implementation for details.](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/xyz/danoz/recyclerviewfastscroller/sample/fragment/RecyclerViewWithSectionIndicatorFragment.java)

Comment: Nice. Didn't like the colors of the items though :) . Can it handle the SectionIndexer somehow ? For example, to show a bubble like on Lollipop's contacts app, of the current letter ?

Comment: I'll be adding additional implementations like that this week! Just wanted to show a basic example first :)

Comment: ok, I will grant you the reward, but I still want to see those features ... :) 
Would also be nice to see horizontal scrolling, and making it look Material design like on Lollipop.

Comment: I've updated the project to include a SectionIndicator that can interface with a SectionIndexer. Check out the github for details.

Comment: Thank you. Hope it will become easier to switch between ListView/GridView and RecyclerView now.

Comment: @DanielSmith why the min SDK start from 14?? Please return it to at least API9+

Comment: If you using VerticalRecyclerViewFastScroller with SwipeRefreshLayout don't put fastScroller into it, put it outside.

Comment: Observed this is not smooth on scroll. It is jumping.

Comment: Doesn't support StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: 2 years has been passed, and it's not under active development. So many unresolved issues

Answer (score 13):

The Android Support Library 26.0.0 now supports `fastScrollEnabled`

New fastScrollEnabled boolean flag for RecyclerView.

If enabled, fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable, fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable, fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable, and fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable must be set.

Sample - https://android.jlelse.eu/fast-scrolling-with-recyclerview-2b89d4574688

Comment: Interesting! So how do you show the bubble with the text, as you drag it?

Comment: Just to mention that those drawables must be StateListDrawable's and you also have to set drawables for both axis.

Comment: i've just implement fastScroll use support library 26.0.1, it's only show fast scroll bar, must custom to show bubble text

Comment: What do you mean by drawable must be StateListDrawable?

Comment: @Shrikant statelist drawable is when you implement an item with `state_pressed="true"`, item with `state_selected="true"` and just the normal item within the `selector`. So you will have 3 items in the selector.

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of unanswered questions about `RecyclerView` and **fast-scroll/section indexer**, let's try to regroup and gather our opinions and information here.

**The short  answer is:** **NO, you can't enable the fast-scroll** because [**RecyclerView**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java) does not contain a [**FastScroller**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java) object and nor any related logical-state variables. This because `RecyclerView` is not an [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html).

On the other hand, it's not impossible to implement a `RecyclerView` which contains a dumped version of `FastScroller` and the necessary logic for the fast-scrolling, but I have not seen any implementation of this so far.

Please share your consideration about that or if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: This is a nice idea. Hope I will have the time to try it out and implement it myself.

Comment: `RecyclerView` was not meant to be used with a FastScroller. It is agains its philosophy and design idea of infinite list. But there is nothing that will stop one from trying though :-)

Comment: Please delete your answer as it will confuse everyone now that it's completely wrong

Answer (score 5):

FastScroller  functionality is added from android library 26.0.0 for **RecyclerView**

compile dependency

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

add depedency to project.gradle

```
     maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

your recyclerview.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tool:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/songlist"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
              app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
                app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
                app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
                app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
               /></LinearLayout>
```

thumb.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:topRightRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="44dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="44dp" />

    <padding
        android:paddingLeft="22dp"
        android:paddingRight="22dp" />

    <solid android:color="#f73831" />

</shape>
```

line.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/dark_grey" />

    <padding
        android:top="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

thumb_drawable.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" 
            android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

line_drawble.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line" 
            android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Some resources are missing: line_dark , line_dark , dark_grey . Where did you find this information? Is there a tutorial/article about it? When was it added (time) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper , i forget to  change some elements name (i put as same as my code), i didnt find this information, above code is part of my self project ,i currently working on. i think is good share info, that i how i slove this problem.

Comment: How did you find about it, then? And can you please update it so that I can try it out?

Comment: @androiddeveloper upvote here is link of documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0

Comment: and for more modification use this documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: I don't see in the docs of RecyclerView (here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html ) anything about fast-scroller. In fact when I search for "fast" nothing is there... Where did you find what needs to be done, and how the drawables should be used and be set?

Comment: I've now tested it. Seems to work well. I've upvoted this solution. Here's a nice article about it: https://android.jlelse.eu/fast-scrolling-with-recyclerview-2b89d4574688

Answer (score 4):

You can as well use A-Z Fastscroll for RecyclerView. It is the iOS style.

https://github.com/code-computerlove/FastScrollRecyclerView/

How to use it:

- Replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `com.codecomputerlove.fastscrollrecyclerviewdemo.FastScrollRecyclerView`
- Your adapter needs to implement FastScrollRecyclerViewInterface and override `getMapIndex()`. The function should return the mapIndex. Look into `calculateIndexesForName()` for inspiration on how to create it. Once created pass it to the adapter in the constructor.
- Create an instance of `FastScrollRecyclerViewItemDecoration` and add it on your RecyclerView
  `FastScrollRecyclerViewItemDecoration decoration = new FastScrollRecyclerViewItemDecoration(this); mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);`
- add `<dimen name="fast_scroll_overlay_text_size">100dp</dimen>` to your
  `/values/dimens.xml` file. This is the dp size of the overlayed letter

Comment: This is actually nice, but it's IOS style. The fast-scroller is for Android.

Answer (score 3):

You can try our lib: https://github.com/FutureMind/recycler-fast-scroll. It's still in early development, but was built specifically to deal with smoothness issue we experienced with other libraries. It uses a little bit different mechanism. It supports horizontal LayoutManager as well and will also support multi-column setups in near future.

Edit: there are some neat customisation options now.

Comment: RecyclerView works on API 7 and above. Why do you need API 15 for just a simple view? Also, it has a bug: use the fast scroller to scroll somewhere, then scroll normally. The scoller will jump from its current position.

Comment: The reason is probably the same as in your repo. I could change it to 11 immediately but I will change it to 7 when I have time to port animations to 7. Thanks for noticing this bug, I must have introduced it after adding horizontal scroll feature

Comment: Sorry. I didn't remember what I did back then. But I did plan on making it work on pre-API 11.

Comment: This one supports StaggeredGridLayoutManager out of the box

Answer (score 1):

There is a provision of implementing scroll bars with `RecycleView` and its `LayoutManager`.

For example: [`computeVerticalScrollExtent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeHorizontalScrollExtent()) , [`computeVerticalScrollOffset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeHorizontalScrollOffset()) and [`computeVerticalScrollRange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeVerticalScrollRange()) can provide information for always positioning a vertical scroll thumb at correct place.

These methods are also there in [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) for delegating actual measurements. So the `LayoutManager` implementation used must support these measurements.

Also, drag touch on scroll thumb can be intercepted by overriding [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) of `RecyclerView`. And after calculating the desired scroll, [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)) can be called to update `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it by code? I asked this in order to really find a way to put the fast-scroller, and as I'm a newb in RecyclerView, it's quite hard for me to do it on my short spare time

Answer (score 1):

This new library was based on framework launcher's fast scroller: https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll

[Usage](https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll#usage):

```
new FastScrollerBuilder(recyclerView).build();
```

Optionally implement [`PopupTextProvider`](https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/zhanghai/android/fastscroll/PopupTextProvider.java) in the adapter.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Just enable fast scrolling and add thumb, tracker for scroll bar like below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rv_sensors"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable" />
```

Comment: Yes, this question was asked way before this thing was possible. I wonder though how customizable it is. Is it possible to set how the bubble looks like? Is it possible to even have the bubble? How can I set what to show in the bubble?

Answer (score 0):

The fast-scroller in android studio is still very buggy as it's only based on xml,so I went digging for external libraries that could implement fast scrolling. You can get it
[here](https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll). Very easy to implement and customize.

Comment: Seems nice, but also seems too strict about the rules. Requiring us to know the height of each item, and also having the same height for each item type...