# Fast Scrolling a RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I wanted to display news items as cardviews in a recyclerview. however, display is getting stuttered whenever i try scrolling fast through the list. How can i enable a smoother scrolling?

Comment: Reffer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview

Comment: I think that there are many inflating in adapter, try to move inflating lines out of the getview

Answer (score 0):

I think your UIThread is blocked by running complicated task.
So task like network call,image fetching,saving etc should be done in separate task..
Can you show your codes..

Comment: I use Volley for all the above mentioned tasks. It scrolls perfectly fine when a list view is used. Recyclerview is the one which is giving me problems