# Use of Scrollbar in RecyclerView

Tags: android

hello guys i am using RecyclerView in android and implemented successfully, Now i want to add scrollbar so my xml code is

`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollIndicators="start"
        android:scrollbarSize="59dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@mipmap/photos_selected"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />`

now scrollbar is showing but i want that when we press on scrollbar image and move in top so screen should be also scroll and same as for move down to scrollbar image but its not working.

Comment: There is no default implementation for this. You can use [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2673) library.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView doesn't support fast scroll by default. You need to use some other library for achieving the same.

Try this -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494241/1741586

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: what is the difference between my code and in this code...is there any issue  or something wrong ..in my code?