# Recyclerview not scroll smoothly

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

-->Here is the code of Activity that contain recyclerview   I have done following code
 this is the code of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
                PaginationAdapterCallback,StoryAdapter.OnClickImageListener{
@Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
@Bind(R.id.drawer)
ImageView ivDrawer;
@Bind(R.id.imgHome)
ImageView imgHome;
@Bind(R.id.imgFriendRequest)
FrameLayout imgFriendRequest;
@Bind(R.id.imgTimeline)
ImageView imgTimeline;
@Bind(R.id.drawerListView)
ListView drawerListView;
@Bind(R.id.etSearch)
TextView etSearch;
@Bind(R.id.nestedScroll)
ScrollView scroll;
@Bind(R.id.imgGallery)
ImageView imgGallery;
@Bind(R.id.imgNotification)
FrameLayout imgNotification;
@Bind(R.id.imgChat)
FrameLayout imgChat;
@Bind(R.id.error_btn_retry)
Button error_btn_retry;
@Bind(R.id.gestureImg)
ImageView gestureImg;
SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefresh;
@Bind(R.id.rvHairList)
RecyclerView rvPostList;
@Bind(R.id.rvStoryList)
RecyclerView rvStoryList;
@Bind(R.id.progressBar1)
ProgressBar pb;
@Bind(R.id.main_progress)
ProgressBar progressBar;
@Bind(R.id.llDrawer)
LinearLayout llDrawer;
static TextView notiCount;
static TextView msgCount;
static ImageView imgNoti;
static ImageView imgMsg;
static TextView friendCount;
static ImageView imgFnd;
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private StoryAdapter storyAdapter;
@Bind(R.id.mainLayout)
LinearLayout mainLayout;
@Bind(R.id.error_layout)
LinearLayout errorLayout;
@Bind(R.id.error_txt_cause)
TextView txtError;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private LinearLayoutManager linearlayoutManager;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 218;
private List<MediaItem> mMediaSelectedList;
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
private static int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
String req, status, text, tagId,tagdId, imagePath, fcmid;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
static String id;
protected Handler handler;
public  static  boolean mboolean = false;
private boolean isLastPage = false;
private int TOTAL_PAGES  ;
private int currentPage = PAGE_START;
private static final int PAGE_START = 1;
long totalSize = 0;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private AllPostService movieService;
static Uri defaultSoundUri;
static Ringtone r;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 101;
private String selectedImagePath;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    rvPostList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    swiperefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    friendCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendCount);
    imgNoti = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNoti);
    imgFnd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFnd);
    imgMsg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMsg);
    notiCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notiCount);
    msgCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgCount);
    storyAdapter=new StoryAdapter(this);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rvStoryList.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
    rvStoryList.setAdapter(storyAdapter);
    initDrawer();
    init();
    swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new 
   SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshContent();
        }
    });
}
    private void init() {
    isLoading=true;
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this);
    linearlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    rvPostList.setLayoutManager(linearlayoutManager);
    rvPostList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvPostList.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    movieService = AllPostApi.getClient().create(AllPostService.class);
    loadFirstPage();
    setScrollListener();
}
private int mTotalScrolled = 0;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
private void setScrollListener(){
    rvPostList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            mTotalScrolled += dy;
            int topRowVerticalPosition =
                    (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 
                           0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
            swiperefresh.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = linearlayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = linearlayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = linearlayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        isLoading = true;
                        currentPage += 1;
                        loadNextPage();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private Call<Post> callTopRatedMoviesApi() {
    return movieService.getTopRatedMovies(
            id,
            currentPage
    );
}
private void loadFirstPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadFirstPage: ");
    // To ensure list is visible when retry button in error view is clicked
    hideErrorView();
    callTopRatedMoviesApi().enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            hideErrorView();
            List<Result> results = fetchResults(response);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(results.size() > 0){
                postAdapter.addFirtTime(results);
            }
            if (currentPage < TOTAL_PAGES) postAdapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
            isLoading=false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            showErrorView(t);
        }
    });
}
private void showErrorView(Throwable throwable) {
    if (errorLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtError.setText(fetchErrorMessage(throwable));
    }
}
private String fetchErrorMessage(Throwable throwable) {
    String errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);
    if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
        errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_no_internet);
    } else if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
        errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_timeout);
    }
    return errorMsg;
}
private void hideErrorView() {
    if (errorLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
private List<Result> fetchResults(Response<Post> response) {
    Post topRatedMovies = response.body();
    TOTAL_PAGES = (int) topRatedMovies.count_page;
    return topRatedMovies.friendList;
}
 private void loadNextPage() {
    if (currentPage > TOTAL_PAGES)
    {
        isLastPage = true;
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "loadNextPage: " + currentPage);
    callTopRatedMoviesApi().enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            postAdapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            isLoading = false;

            List<Result> results = fetchResults(response);
            if(results.size() > 0) {
                postAdapter.addAll(results);
            }
            if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES)
                postAdapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else {
                isLastPage = true;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            postAdapter.showRetry(true, fetchErrorMessage(t));
            if(currentPage>0)
                currentPage--;
        }
    });
}
private void refreshContent(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            currentPage = 1;
            isLoading=true;
            isLastPage=false;
            movieService = 
            AllPostApi.getClient().create(AllPostService.class);
            loadFirstPage();
            swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
@OnClick(R.id.error_btn_retry)
public void Onerror_btn_retryClick() {
    if(isNetworkConnected()){
        currentPage = 1;
        isLoading=true;
        isLastPage=false;
        movieService = AllPostApi.getClient().create(AllPostService.class);
        loadFirstPage();
    }else {
    }
}
@OnClick(R.id.llHome)
public void OnHomeClick() {
    scroll.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
}
}
```

Below Adapter for recyclerview that used

```
 public class PostAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Activity activity;
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private List<Result> movieResults;
private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;
private boolean retryPageLoad = false;
String id;
private String errorMsg;
private int pos = 0;
long countvalue;
private PaginationAdapterCallback mCallback;
PostHolder postHolder;
public PostAdapter(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.mCallback = (PaginationAdapterCallback) activity;
    movieResults = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM:
            viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoadingVH(v2);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}
@NonNull
private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, 
 LayoutInflater inflater) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new PostHolder(v1);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Result result = movieResults.get(position);
    id = Utils.getPref(activity,"rid","");
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case ITEM:
            final PostHolder movieVH = (PostHolder) holder;
            postHolder = movieVH;
            if(pos == position){
                movieVH.adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                AdRequest re= new AdRequest.Builder()
               .build();
                movieVH.adView.loadAd(re);
            }else{
                movieVH.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if(result.likeCount > 0){
                movieVH.likeCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                movieVH.likeCount.setText(result.likeCount+" Likes");
            }else {
                movieVH.likeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Log.e("position null",position+"");
            if(result.likeStatus.equals("Like")){
                movieVH.imgLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                movieVH.imgLike.setChecked(true);
            }else {
                movieVH.imgLike.setChecked(false);
            }
            movieVH.imgLike.setTag(movieVH);
            movieVH.imgLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CallForAddLike(result.postid,result.sharid,
                            result.rid, v,position);
                }
            });
            if(result.commentCount> 0){
                movieVH.commentCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                movieVH.commentCount.setText(result.commentCount+" 
  Comments");
            }else {
                movieVH.commentCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if(result.shareCount > 0){
                movieVH.shareCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                movieVH.shareCount.setText(result.shareCount+" Shares");
            }else {
                movieVH.shareCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            movieVH.postedTime.setText(result.dateTime);
            movieVH.imgComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity,CommentActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("postid",result.postid);
                    i.putExtra("shareid",result.sharid);
                    i.putExtra("receiver",result.rid);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            Glide.with(activity)
                    .load(result.path)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String 
     model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            movieVH.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable 
  resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean 
  isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            movieVH.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(movieVH.postedImg);
            Picasso.with(activity)
                    .load(result.profilePicture)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
                    .into(movieVH.userPic);
            if(result.message.equals("")){
                movieVH.postedMsg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                movieVH.postedMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                movieVH.postedMsg.setText(result.message);
            }
            if(result.poststatus.length() == 0){
                movieVH.userName.setText(result.fname+" "+
                        result.lname);
            }else {
                String CurrentString = result.poststatus;
                String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
                if(separated.length>1){
                    movieVH.userName.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                            result.fname+" "+result.lname +
                                    "<font color=\"#ADACAB\">" +
                                    " with " +
                                    "</font>" + separated[0]+"<font color=\"#ADACAB\">" + " and " + "</font>"
                                    +String.valueOf(separated.length-1)+" others "));
                }else {
                    movieVH.userName.setText(Html.fromHtml(result.fname+" "+
                            result.lname +"<font color=\"#ADACAB\">" +
                            " with " +
                            "</font>" + separated[0] ));
                }
            }
            if(id.equals(result.rid)){
                movieVH.dltPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                movieVH.dltPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            movieVH.commentCount.setOnClickListener(new 
                  View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, CommentList.class);
                    i.putExtra("shareid",result.sharid);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            movieVH.likeCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
                 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, LikeActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("shareId",result.sharid);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            break;
        case LOADING:
            LoadingVH loadingVH = (LoadingVH) holder;
            if (retryPageLoad) {
                loadingVH.mErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingVH.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadingVH.mErrorTxt.setText(errorMsg != null ? errorMsg : 
   activity.getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown));
            } else {
                loadingVH.mErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadingVH.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
public void removeAt(int position) {
    movieResults.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, movieResults.size());
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == movieResults.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING 
  : ITEM;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieResults == null ? 0 : movieResults.size();
}
public void addAll(List<Result> moveResults) {
    final int pos=movieResults.size();
    movieResults.addAll(moveResults);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(pos,moveResults.size());
}
public void cleardata() {
    movieResults.clear();
    movieResults=new ArrayList<>();
}
public void remove(Result r) {
    int position = movieResults.indexOf(r);
    if (position > -1) {
        movieResults.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getItemCount() == 0;
}
public void addFirtTime(List<Result> moveResults) {
    movieResults.clear();
    movieResults=new ArrayList<>();
    movieResults.addAll(moveResults);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    add(new Result());
}
public void removeLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    int position = movieResults.size() - 1;
    Result result = getItem(position);
    if (result != null) {
        movieResults.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
public Result getItem(int position) {
    return movieResults.get(position);
}
public void add(Result r) {
    movieResults.add(r);
    notifyItemInserted(movieResults.size()-1);
}
protected class LoadingVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
         View.OnClickListener {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mRetryBtn;
    private TextView mErrorTxt;
    private LinearLayout mErrorLayout;
    public LoadingVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_progress);
        mRetryBtn = (ImageButton) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_retry);
        mErrorTxt = (TextView) 
  itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_errortxt);
        mErrorLayout = (LinearLayout) 
      itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_errorlayout);
        mRetryBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mErrorLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.loadmore_retry:
            case R.id.loadmore_errorlayout:
                showRetry(false, null);
                mCallback.retryPageLoad();
                break;
        }
    }
}
public void showRetry(boolean show, @Nullable String errorMsg) {
    retryPageLoad = show;
    notifyItemChanged(movieResults.size() - 1);
    if (errorMsg != null) this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
}

private void CallForAddLike(final String postId, final String shareId, final String receiverId,
                            final View holder, final int position) {
    new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put(RequestParamsUtils.U_ID, id);
                params.put(RequestParamsUtils.POST_ID, postId);
                params.put(RequestParamsUtils.SHARE_ID, shareId);
                params.put(RequestParamsUtils.RECEIVER, receiverId);
                Debug.e("sent parameters", params.toString());
                AsyncHttpClient clientPhotos = AsyncHttpRequest.newRequest();
                clientPhotos.post(new URLs().ADD_LIKE, params, new ResponseHandler(activity,
                        holder,position));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.e("showProgress Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
public class ResponseHandler extends AsyncResponseHandler {
    PostHolder holder ;
    int position;
    Activity activity;
    public ResponseHandler(Activity context,final View holder,
                           final int position) {
        super(context);
        this.position = position;
        this.activity=context;
        this.holder= (PostHolder) holder.getTag();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        super.onFinish();
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.e("ResponseHandler onFinish Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        try {
            Debug.e("ResponseHandler", "onSuccess" + response);
            if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                final AddLike styleListRider = new Gson().fromJson(
                        response, new TypeToken<AddLike>() {
                        }.getType());
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (styleListRider.statusCode == 1) {
                            if(styleListRider.message.equals("Like 
      Successfully")){    
    movieResults.get(position).likeStatus="Like";
                                countvalue = 
    movieResults.get(position).likeCount++;
                                Log.e("position null",position+"");                                    
   holder.imgLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                                if(movieResults.get(position).likeCount > 0)
  {
  holder.likeCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 holder.likeCount.setText(movieResults.get(position).likeCount+" Likes");
                                }else {
 holder.likeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }else{
movieResults.get(position).likeStatus="UnLike";
                                countvalue = 
movieResults.get(position).likeCount--;
 holder.imgLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlike);
                                if(movieResults.get(position).likeCount > 0)
 {
 holder.likeCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 holder.likeCount.setText(movieResults.get(position).likeCount+" Likes");
                                }else {
 holder.likeCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }                                   
                            }
                        } else if(styleListRider.statusCode == 0){
                            Log.e("message",styleListRider.message);                              
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.e("ResponseHandler onSuccess Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String content) {
        Debug.e("Response ", "onFailure" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;
    @Bind(R.id.postedImg)
    ImageView postedImg;
    @Bind(R.id.postedTime)
    TextView postedTime;
    @Bind(R.id.userPic)
    ImageView userPic;
    @Bind(R.id.imgLike)
    CheckBox imgLike;
    @Bind(R.id.userName)
    TextView userName;
    @Bind(R.id.postedMsg)
    TextView postedMsg;
    @Bind(R.id.imgShare)
    ImageView imgShare;
    @Bind(R.id.dltPost)
    ImageView dltPost;
    @Bind(R.id.imgComment)
    ImageView imgComment;
    @Bind(R.id.likeCount)
    TextView likeCount;
    @Bind(R.id.commentCount)
    TextView commentCount;
    @Bind(R.id.shareCount)
    TextView shareCount;
    @Bind(R.id.videoLayout)
    FrameLayout videoLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.likeLayout)
    LinearLayout likeLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.viewLine)
    View viewLine;
    @Bind(R.id.viewLineAd)
    View viewLineAd;
    @Bind(R.id.adView)
    NativeExpressAdView adView;
    @Bind(R.id.progress)
    ProgressBar progress;
    @Bind(R.id.commentLayout)
    LinearLayout commentLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.shareLayout)
    LinearLayout shareLayout;
    public PostHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.view = itemView;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
}
```

Need help and thank you in advance

### Recyclerview Scroll but not so smooth

Comment: XML code please? by any means do u using Nested Recycler View?

Comment: i am not able to share xml because it is too long to mention so can u help me how i can share it ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @msh.nayan  i have used scrollview

Comment: @JeroenHeier thank you for guide

Answer (score 1):

Any code inside OnBindViewHolder should be as fast as possible else scrolling will not be smooth so try to do long work on another thread. example you are using AdBuilder to load ad this will take much time and will make scrolling issues.

Comment: i have tried without ad but still problem is same as previous , no effect to scroll

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: as u can see in code i have already added that but no hope at all

Comment: Have you tried this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27798212/4116560  ?

Comment: @sam not useful

Comment: Oh, I thought it might be of some help!