# Detect fast scroll in recylcer view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fastscroll

In my project I have RecyclerView with fast scroll and I need show some view only on fast scroll event (not for default scroll events). Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fling by fast scroll, then you can register a `RecyclerView.OnFlingListener` to your `RecyclerView`

Ref:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnFlingListener