# Fast scrolling in Xamarin CollectionView

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For `ListView` one can activate fast scrolling by setting `android:ListView.IsFastScrollEnabled="True"` on it. With this option the scrollbar becomes touchable to scroll through large lists fast. Unfortunately this property does not have an effect on `CollectionView`. Is there a way to get a similar behavior on it?

Without fast scrolling:

[image: Without fast scrolling]

With fast scrolling:

[image: With fast scrolling]

Answer (score 1):

As usual everything is possible, but there is no easy way to do this.

`ListView` in Xamarin.Forms uses `ListView` on Android which has fast scroll built into the control.

`CollectionView` in Xamarin.Forms uses `RecyclerView` and it doesn't have fast scroll built-in.

Overall this means that you can only write a custom renderer starting with Xamarin code from github and apply advice from here: [How to add a fast-scroller to the RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798212/how-to-add-a-fast-scroller-to-the-recyclerview)